# self-contained ASP.Net Core app doesn't run on Mac

Tags: asp.net, .net, macos, .net-core, self-contained

Any idea how I can find the cause of this issue? Mac terminal just responds with "command not found" trying to run an ASP.NET core app published using self-contained deployment.

- using .NET Core SDK v.1.1
- the app is just demo code taken from this blog :  https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/02/14/running-vuejs-on-aspnet-core-apps/
- deployment is done as described by Scott Hanselman here :  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SelfcontainedNETCoreApplications.aspx
- specified runtime "osx.10.12-x64". Tried to run it on a Mac Mini with Intel Core 2 Duo and macOS Sierra installed.
- No problems using the "win10-x64" deploy on a Win10 machine which doesn't have .NET Core installed.

Comment: Which command triggered that error and what is `ls` output in the same folder? You don't reveal your steps with enough information.

Comment: The test application is called "VueTest" so the OSX deploy contains a file "VueTest" which I try to run : "VueTest" or "sudo VueTest" return "command not found". The folder contains about 200 files, the whole .NET core runtime (around 50MB, as opposed to around 10MB when I use framework-dependent deployment instead of self-contained).

Comment: I have uploaded the full OSX deploy here : http://www.tinybox.rocks/vuetest_osx_10_12_x64.zip The working Win10 deploy is here : http://www.tinybox.rocks/vuetest_win10_x64.zip  Content of the 2 app folders is almost identical, except for the VueTest.exe (win) as opposed to VueTest (osx) and a few .dlls on windows (like coreclr.dll) which are .dylib files on osx (like libcoreclr.dylib)

Comment: You should run it as `./VueTest` if you have learnt have to use macOS ABCs.

Comment: this is embarrassing... Of course you're right, and that indeed solves the "problem". It's obvious that I'm a Mac/Linux noob. Lex Li I do appreciate that you took the time to respond to such stupid mistake.

Comment: Unfortunately I now still have the same problem on Linux. I installed a fresh Debian 8 64-bit virtual machine and copied the self-contained debian deploy to it (built for runtime "debian.8-x64"). Files are also here : http://www.tinybox.rocks/vuetest_debian_8_x64.zip  Again "command not found" when I do "sudo ./VueTest". Not sure which are the prerequisites to run a self-contained ASP.Net Core app, I followed the screenshot at https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxdebian and installed curl, libunwind8 and gettext. I hope I'm making another stupid mistake...

Comment: I don't have access to your machine, so can only guess you don't run `chmod a+x VueTest`. It is not embarrassing at all, as we were all noobs the first day. Find a good enough Linux/macOS beginner book and you will soon know much better where to go.

Comment: And you were spot on again... I ran through the many posts of people struggling with .NET Core, while I overlooked the very basic errors like this one - again. Anyway, I have the dummy app running on Win10, Debian and OSX now, without .NET Core install. Still many challenges ahead but for now I'm a happy man - now I'd better learn some basic stuff first. Thanks again Lex Li!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OK. So to summarize. Microsoft does make .NET Core apps cross platform, but the Windows developers must learn carefully some macOS and Linux ABCs before diving to another operating system.

Common issues are,

1. You need to run the program at terminal by calling `./executable_name`, and this is a convention.
2. You need to grant the executable the rights to execute, by calling `chmod a+x executable_name` (most Linux distributions require this).